# Resolve shifts in CSS nav menu

Tags: html, css

I have shifts in my NAV menu that I am having trouble resolving.  The menu is CSS & HTML based.  Issue 1 > Mousing over Headings 1 through 4 causes a slight shift to the right of any headers to the right.  How do I stop that?  Issue 2 > Mousing over Header4 reveals a sub menu that initially appears fine. But when you hover over the sub menu the item of focus gets larger than the other sub menu items, so it looks sloppy. How do I correct this? Issue 3 > The Setting menu's sub menu (last menu item) expands in width when the sub menu is hovered over.  I'd like it to be the same width whether it is being hovered over or not. How?  Perhaps the same answer as #2.

Lastly, a general observation I'd like some feedback on.  My original CSS for this NAV seemed pretty straight forward to me. As I've observed things that need to be "adjusted" I've added a tweak here, another there, and still another there, until now it seems completely convoluted. Is this common, or am I just mucking things up with bad tweaks?  Thanks for your help.

CSS:

```
/* NAVIGATION */
#menu{
    padding 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #003366;
}

.nav ul li{
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
    padding: 10px 22px 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dadada;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #003366;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #336699;
    /* Adding the padding makes the hover selection not jump */
    padding: 10px 22px 10px 26px;
    left: -4px;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    /*width: 403px;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.75);
    border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
}

.nav ul li ul li{
    width: 143px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    background-color: #336699;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover{
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    left: 0px;
}

.nav ul li ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover a{
    color: #000;
}

#settings {
    padding: 6px 22px;
    /*vertical-align:middle;*/
    float:right;
    border-right:none;
}

#settings:hover {
    padding: 6px 18px;
}

#settings > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -124px;
    top: 27px;
}
```

Web Page:

```
<?php

$access = 0

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nav</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="basicnav2.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="menu">
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Heading1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Heading2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Heading3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Heading4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                            <li>
                        </ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Heading5</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    if ($access < 2)
                    { ?>
                    <li id="settings">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/settings.png" alt="Settings" height="25" width="25"></a>
                        <ul id ="settings ul">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="textarea">
            <p>This is sample text.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for this part of your code:

```
/* Adding the padding makes the hover selection not jump */
padding: 10px 22px 10px 26px;
left: -4px;
```

Removing it appears to fix the problem at my end.

Comment: The -4px was added so that the hover selection matches up with the left margin of its "un-hovered" counterpart.  Otherwise there is a 4px shift (gap) to the right.  In other words, the left margins don't line up.  The padding was added to stop the hover selection from collapsing (getting smaller).  If it isn't there the selection that is hovered over gets smaller.  I'm just trying to get the NAV menu to be stable.  You mouse over one thing, and everything stays the same size, in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Issue1: 
The expansion of li elements is caused due to addition of 
    left: -4px;

in .nav ul li:hover css section
However, removing it is causing little space on left of each li.

Issue 2 solution is removing the padding in the same above css section :

```
padding: 10px 22px 10px 26px;
```

Instead just use below line to jump to sub-menu:

```
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pdfn0auw/2/

Edit : new demo included

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I got rid of all of the padding in .nav ul li:hover, and that improved things. I kept the -4px though. Without it the sub-menu doesn't line up with the left margin of the parent and I want it to.  Now the only item in the menu that changes size when a selection is moused over is the selection, which collapses by 4px. I'd rather have it stay the same size too, but if I have to pick one of the two outcomes this seems more appealing.  A shame though... seems like eliminating the shifts should be doable.  I'm still tinkering with it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I have done some changes and now there is no flickering while switching between navigation menu.
Try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pdfn0auw/2/

Please stretch the output section of fiddle to have a better look